# Kivy service won't restart/ autorestart

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build a rudimentary app with Kivy on android to understand the fundamentals of service.

I am trying to make my **service restart**, but I didn't succeed.

the service work but doesn’t restart
the code doesn't give an error
Does someone know what I did wrong?

#### ADB Log

```
ActivityManager: Process org.kivy.oscservice:service_Pong (pid 27830) has died: svc SVC

01-30 23:55:00.012 1315 4034 I ActivityManager: Process org.kivy.oscservice:service_Pong (pid 29178) has died: svcb SVC 01-30 
23:55:00.012 1315 4034 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service org.kivy.oscservice/.ServicePong in 1000ms 
01-30 23:55:01.041 1315 1471 I ActivityManager: Start proc 29428:org.kivy.oscservice:service_Pong/u0a165 for service org.kivy.oscservice/.ServicePong 
01-30 23:55:01.169 29428 29428 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.kivy.oscservice:service_Pong, PID: 29428 
01-30 23:55:01.169 29428 29428 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.kivy.oscservice.ServicePong@ae87b11 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
```

*You can directly have access to those file on this github page: https://github.com/Qypol342/kivy-service-restart

**the architecture of my file:**

```
          -buildozer.spec
          -scr
            |-> main.py
            |-> service.py
```

**my .spec file:**

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Kivy service restart

# (str) Package name
package.name = restartservice

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.kivy

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = src

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version.regex = __version__ = '(.*)'
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,plyer

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
services = Pong:service.py

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 28

# (int) Minimum API required. You will need to set the android.ndk.api to be as low as this value.
#android.minapi = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19c

# (int) Android NDK API to use (optional). This is the minimum API your app will support. 
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = True

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
p4a.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
# p4a.source_dir = /home/gabriel/dev/python-for-android/

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 0

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

**my main.py file:**

```py
# coding: utf8
__version__ = '0.2'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.utils import platform

from jnius import autoclass


from plyer import notification


SERVICE_NAME = u'{packagename}.Service{servicename}'.format(
    packagename=u'org.kivy.oscservice',
    servicename=u'Pong'
)


KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        
        
        Button:
            text: 'start service'
            on_press: app.start_service()
        
'''

class ClientServerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.service = None
        # self.start_service()

        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.root

    def start_service(self):

        if platform == 'android':
            service = autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
            
            mActivity = autoclass(u'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
            argument = ''
            
            service.start(mActivity, argument)




            

            notification.notify(title='main', message='service starting')


       



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientServerApp().run()
```

**my service.py file:**

```py
import datetime
from plyer import notification
from jnius import autoclass




if __name__ == '__main__':
    notification.notify(title='service', message=str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
    pyservice = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonService')
    pyservice.mService.setAutoRestartService(True)
```